# What is the default location for rsync uploads?

Tags: command-line, rsync

I uploaded a local text file omitting the remote location and can't find the file (Ubuntu 16.04).

```
rsync -chavzP dump.sql user@ip-address
```

It's not in my home directory or anywhere else that I can tell:

```
find / -name dump.sql -print
```

I can re-upload with a remote location, but would like to at least find and remove that 6GB dump that I'm not using.

Comment: You miss `:` after `user@ip-address`.

Comment: Yeah, I used `rsync -chavzP dump.sql user@ip-address:/home/user` to fix it. So what happened to my first file? According to my terminal it uploaded.

Comment: You should have `user@ip-address` file in the directory where you ran rsync.

Comment: Ah! There it is, on my local. Without that `:` rsync assumed remote credentials was a filename. Thanks @ArkadiuszDrabczyk :-)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk can you please formulate this as an answer and post it? :)

Comment: ok, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You miss `:` after `user@ip-address`. Without that you will create
`user@ip-address` file in the directory where you ran rsync.

Comment: Thanks! I found the file (on my local machine) and removed it.